# How to wait for a function for finish in angular 4?

Tags: angular

Below is my code, in the for loop I call the delete method, but I want to wait for funcion to finish, before call it again. I have a company and a Project class, in the Project class there is a company array, this contains the list of the companies which is connected to the project. The reason why I want to wait for funcion to finish, because when I want to delete multiple companies from the project, this call multiple delete method in the same time and delete only one company in the same time.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from '../company';
import { CompaniesService } from './companies.service';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-companies',
    templateUrl: './companies.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./companies.component.css']
})

export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(
        private companiesService: CompaniesService,
        private sharedService: SharedService
    ){}

    companies: Company[];

    getCompanies(): void{
        this.companiesService
        .getCompanies()
        .subscribe(companies => {this.companies = companies, this.isLoading=false});
    }

    method(): void{
        let array=this.companies;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i].selected)
            {
                this.delete(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    delete(company: Company): void {
        this.companies = this.companies.filter(h => h !== company);
        this.sharedService.deleteProjectFromCompany(company);
        this.companiesService.delete(company).subscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return in your method Observables and then put them in an array.
After this, you call `Observable.forkJoin()` and wait all to resolve with subscribe.

Something like this code:

```js
public deleteAll(deletingList: {id: number}[]): Observable<void[]> {
    const deleteList: Observable<void> = [];
    deletingList.forEach(item => deleteList.push(this.delete(item.id)));
    return Observable.forkJoin(deleteList);
}

public delete(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete(...);
}
```

At first I would rename your "method" into "delete":

```js
/**
    Filter only selected companies
    Add every deleting company Observable
    Do a forkJoin: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html
*/ 
public delete(): Observable<Company[]> {
    const deletingCompanies: Array<Observable<void>> = [];
    this.companies
        .filter(company => company.selected)
        .forEach(company => deletingCompanies.push(this._delete(company)));

    return Observable.forkJoin(deletingCompanies);
}

private _delete(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
    this.companies = this.companies.filter(h => h !== company);
    this.sharedService.deleteProjectFromCompany(company);
    return this.companiesService.delete(company);
}
```

If you now subscribe on the "method"-method, all calls are complete on the subscription.

Comment: There is an error:
Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<void>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'undefined[]'.

const deletingCompanies: Observable<void>

Comment: What does `this.companiesService.delete(company);` return? I assumed: `Observable<void>`. I have edited again, maybe now? Which line or method the error occurrs?

Comment: This is the companiesService's delete method:
`delete(company: Company | number): Observable<Company> {
    const id = typeof company === 'number' ? company : company.id;
    const url = `${this.companiesUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.delete<Company>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => (`deleted company id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Company>('delete'))
    );
  }`

Comment: Ok, if you're returning a `Observable<Company>`, you should declare it as such (I've edited my code again)

Comment: Thank you!
Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this is do tha same thing, call the deleteProjectFromCompany the (almost) same time, but now this delete just the last company from the project.

Comment: Is `this.sharedService.deleteProjectFromCompany(company);` returning also an Observable? Because you never subscribe to it, so it don't get executed. You could chain this also with Observable.forkJoin().

Comment: Than you!
You helped a lot! I can't vote, I have only 6 reputation, but when I hit the 15, I will come back and vote up.

Comment: You're welcome. You also should be able to accept my answer :) (instead of an upvote)